# Cbind result of aplucter to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I perform cluster analysis and i must use apcluster library

```
library(apcluster)

## create four synthetic 2D clusters
cl1 <- cbind(rnorm(30, 0.3, 0.05), rnorm(30, 0.7, 0.04))
cl2 <- cbind(rnorm(30, 0.7, 0.04), rnorm(30, 0.4, .05))
cl3 <- cbind(rnorm(20, 0.50, 0.03), rnorm(20, 0.72, 0.03))
cl4 <- cbind(rnorm(25, 0.50, 0.03), rnorm(25, 0.42, 0.04))
x <- rbind(cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4)

## run apcluster() (you may replace the Euclidean distance by a different
## distance, e.g. driving distance, driving time)
apres <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), x, q=0)
```

After the clustering, selected cluster i want to join to x `data.frame` to see
observation and what it cluster. 
I did so

```
cbind(x, mycluster=apres$Clusters)
```

and error

```
Error in apres$Clusters : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

How should i do?

```
 [,1]           [,2]      cluster
  [1,] 0.3671142 0.6204475      2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is that `apres` isn't an S3 class object and using `$` isn't going to work. See `apres` and you will see `@` used in a similar fashion. In particular, as to get the resulting clusters, you want

```
cls <- apres@clusters
```

Next thing is that `cls` is a list of four elements, each elements containing indices of observations belonging to the corresponding cluster. One way then to associate the observation (value) with its cluster (name) would be

```
clsNm <- sort(setNames(unlist(cls), rep(1:length(cls), times = lengths(cls))))
head(clsNm)
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Then we may do what you tried

```
head(cbind(x, cluster = as.integer(names(clsNm))), 2)
#                          cluster
# [1,] 0.2526693 0.6764543       1
# [2,] 0.2781545 0.6774726       1
```